# How to disable right click on a hyperlink in page/popup open in Iframe using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable right click on a Anchor tag/hyperlink in page/popup open in iframe using javascript/jquery?

I have below code logic which works when I open page in iframe but not work when I open popup in Iframe by clicking on link within the Iframe page.

In below example when I right-click on **Open Popup** link its not allowing the right click but when I open popup by clicking Open Popup link it's not working for links in popup.

Any suggestions?

Below sample code snippet for reference -

**TestPage.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="sampleIframe" src="PopupPage.html" width="400" height="150"></iframe>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $('#sampleIframe').load(function() {
            $('#sampleIframe').contents().find('a').each(function() {
                $(this).on("contextmenu", function() {
                    return false;
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PopupPage.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Popup Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    You are on popup page.  
    <a href="javascript:openPopup();">Open Popup</a>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function openPopup() {
            window.open("LinkPage.html", null,
                "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**LinkPage.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Link Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="www.Google.com">Goto Google</a>
    <a href="www.facebook.com">Goto Facebook</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need to **include your script to disable the links in the actual iFrame content**.

To demonstrate, create a jsfiddle with this code *(it will not let me save it to post a link)*

This would be your **"LinkPage.html"**

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:openPopup();">Open Popup</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function openPopup() {
        window.open("http://jsfiddle.net/t45qvtap/1/show", null,
            "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
    }
```

And you will see it working.

Just to explain further, this is the contents of the fiddle that the above code will open in an iFrame, this would be your **"PopupPage.html"**

HTML

```
This content is in an iframe
<div>
    <a href="www.Google.com">Goto Google</a>
    <a href="www.facebook.com">Goto Facebook</a>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('body').contents().find('a').each(function() {
            $(this).on("contextmenu", function() {
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Its working with URL you have metioned in the popup but I am not getting what exactly you have done? Could you please elaborate little?

Comment: All that I have done @SumitDeshpande is move the script to disable the context menu from "TestPage" into "LinkPage".

Comment: Agree that way it will work but is it possible to make it generic such that in case of any popup with link that open inside iframe will get this rule applied without adding this script inside every popup.